# I dont' understand Backbone.js event system. No event for load?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

So I'm building a BB application and I am trying to call a method of my view when the DOM is loaded.

```
LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'load': 'connexion'
    },
    connexion: function(e) {
        var connecte = window.localStorage.getItem("connecte")?true:false;
        alert(connecte);
    }
});
```

So I looked up in the BB documentation and I saw there are no load events. Are the events only related to the model's data? If there are no "document events" with BB, I would need to do this right after:

```
$(function () {
   var view = new LoginView();
   view.connexion();
})
```

Wich is the same than not having an MVC architecture? I mean what is the point of having a controller (a view), if not all code is in methods? Sorry if I don't totally understand MVC architecture.

Comment: When do you imagine `load()` would be called? When you `initialize` the view? Because there is already a callback for that. Or when you `render` or put the element in the DOM? Both of those aren't automatic and require your intervention, in which case you could trigger the `load` event in your view when you need to... There are only a few HTML tags that use trigger a load event (like `<img />`), the default for a backbone view is a `<div/>` element.

Comment: You are right. Also, when and where should I instantiate my View? In the controller's file right under the declaration of the object? Or in the the HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

The MV* architecture of a Backbone application doesn't really have anything to do with the initial application loading process. I think it's customary to either have a load() or init() function which is called once the document is loaded, or create an overall AppView, which does the same. This then begins the process of loading the Backbone application, its views, models and collections, and setting up the router.

Answer (score 0):

You could just call `connexion()` from inside the `initialize` callback of the view:

```
LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options){
        this.connexion();
    },
    connexion: function(e) {
        var connecte = window.localStorage.getItem("connecte")?true:false;
        alert(connecte);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok you removed it ^^.